# STO 3G basis expansion of p orbitals

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

I am expanding $2p_{x},2p_{y},2p_{z}$ (slater type )orbitals in gaussian STO-3G basis as follows,

$$|2p_{x}\rangle=C_{1}x\exp(-\alpha_{1}r^{2})+C_{2}x\exp(-\alpha_{2}r^{2})+C_{3}x\exp(-\alpha_{3}r^{2})$$

$$|2p_{y}\rangle=C_{1}y\exp(-\alpha_{1}r^{2})+C_{2}y\exp(-\alpha_{2}r^{2})+C_{3}y\exp(-\alpha_{3}r^{2})$$

$$|2p_{z}\rangle=C_{1}z\exp(-\alpha_{1}r^{2})+C_{2}z\exp(-\alpha_{2}r^{2})+C_{3}z\exp(-\alpha_{3}r^{2})$$

I thought the value of $C_{1},C_{2},C_{3},\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\alpha_{3}$ are the same for all the $p$ orbitals. I tried to evaluate the following two integral $$\langle2p_{x}2p_{y}||2p_{y}2p_{z}\rangle=\langle2p_{x}2p_{y}|2p_{y}2p_{z}\rangle-\langle2p_{x}2p_{y}|2p_{z}2p_{y}\rangle$$
where,
$$\langle2p_{x}2p_{y}|2p_{y}2p_{z}\rangle=\sum_{i,j,k,l}C_{p_{x}i}C_{p_{y}l}C_{p_{y}j} C_{p_{x}m}\int d^{3}\vec{r_{1}} \int d^{3}\vec{r_{2}}  x_{1} e^{-\alpha_{i}r_{1}^{2}}y_{1}e^{-\alpha_{l}r_{1}^{2}}\frac{1}{|\vec{r_{1}}-\vec{r_{2}}|}y_{2}e^{-\alpha_{j}r_{2}^{2}}z_{2}e^{-\alpha_{m}r_{2}^{2}}$$
The above integral vanishes completely. I think something went wrong in the basis I have chosen or does it really vanish ? I guess my STO-3G expansion is wrong. Can someone help me fixing this please ?

Comment: I really don't get the point. Can you please elaborate ?